# Why maven packege produce 4 jar files?

Tags: maven

When I run `mvn package`,there are 4 files produced in total:

1. foo.jar
2. foo.zip
3. foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
4. foo.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original

Could anyone please explain what leads to this situation?Is it some plugin that I used?

Here is some piece of my `pom.xml`:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 
       <groupId>cn.bar.buzz</groupId>
    <artifactId>foo</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
 
        ... some dependencies
    </dependencies>
      
 
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
 
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/web</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/${profiles.active}</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>cn.bar.service.MyApplication</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
 
 
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>cn.bar.service.AnotherApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
                    <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                    <descriptors>
                        <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                    </descriptors>
                   <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Is maven itself package for me or the plugins? If the latter,which plugin did which part of job?

Comment: You are using maven assembly plugin you must check `assembly.xml` file.

Comment: check this http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

1. `spring-boot-maven-plugin` produce `foo-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and
   `foo.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar.original`
2. maven assembly plugin created zip file
3. maven default procude jar